# Задача "Рассадка в аудитории" Python

Tags: python

Экзамен по берляндскому языку проходит в узкой и длинной аудитории. На экзамен пришло N студентов. Все они посажены в ряд. Таким образом, позиция каждого человека задается координатой на оси Ox (эта ось ведет вдоль длинной аудитории). Два человека могут разговаривать, если расстояние между ними меньше или равно D. Какое наименьшее количество типов билетов должен подготовить преподаватель, чтобы никакие два студента с одинаковыми билетами не могли разговаривать? Выведите способ раздачи преподавателем билетов.

**Формат ввода**
В первой строке входного файла содержится два целых числа N, D (1 ≤ N ≤ 10000; 0 ≤ D ≤ 106). Вторая строка содержит последовательность различных целых чисел X1, X2, ..., XN, где Xi (0 ≤ Xi ≤ 106) обозначает координату вдоль оси Ox i-го студента

**Формат вывода**
В первую строчку выходного файла выведите количество вариантов, а во вторую, разделяя пробелами, номера вариантов студентов в том порядке, в каком они перечислены во входном файле.

```py
N, D = map(int, input().split())


students = [int(x) for x in input().split()]


dicter = dict.fromkeys(students, 1)
students.sort()

count = 1

j = 0
for i in range(N):
    count = 1
    while j < N and students[j] - students[i] <= D:
        dicter[students[j]] = count
        count += 1
        j += 1

print(max(dicter.values()))
print(*dicter.values())
```

Вот мое решение, валится на одном из тестов. В чем косяк?

Comment: С  какой ошибкой валится?

Comment: У вас не принят ни один ответ на ваши вопросы.

Comment: Ну ошибка, в смысле, просто неправильный ответ.

Comment: Квадратичный не проходит по времени, надо 2 указателя, вроде.

Answer (score 0):

Косяк в неправильной раздаче билетов. Например: *N = 4*, *D = 4*, *X = [1, 5, 6, 9]*. Вы раздадите билеты: *1, 2, 1, 2*. Второй и четвёртый
студенты получат билет номер *2*, расстояние между ними - *4*.

Наденем на каждого студента *X<sub>i</sub>* окрестность радиуса *D/2*: *[X<sub>i</sub> - D/2, X<sub>i</sub> + D/2]*. Заметим что если у двух студентов окрестности не пересекаются, они могут отвечать на один и тот же билет. Если пересечение есть, билеты должны быть различны.

Пусть мы научились решать задачу для окрестностей. Как поменяется ответ если все окрестности сместить вправо на *D/2*? Никак не поменяется. Новые окрестности будут иметь вид *[X<sub>i</sub>, X<sub>i</sub> + D]* - с такими иметь дело проще, все числа целые.

`events` - очередь событий из границ окрестностей. Каждый студент *X<sub>i</sub>* порождает два события: *(X<sub>i</sub>, false, i)* и *(X<sub>i</sub> + D, true, i)*. События упорядочены по координате. Если координаты равны, события открывающие окрестности будут размещены до событий закрывающих (другие) окрестности в той же точке.

`n_tickets`, `free_tickets` и `assignment` - статус заметания. `n_tickets` - общее число билетов, выданных до сих пор. `free_tickets` - список билетов, которые выдавались раньше и уже освободились. `assignment` - хранит ответ и используется при обработке закрывающих событий.

Закрывающие события обрабатываются проще всего: освобождающийся билет попадает в список свободных билетов. Всё.

Открывающее событие сложнее. Если есть свободные билеты, любой из них выдаётся студенту: удаляется из списка свободных и записывается в ответ. Если свободных билетов нет, число билетов увеличивается на единицу. Новый билет записывается в ответ.

После обработки всех событий в ответе заполнены все ячейки.

```
import heapq

n, d = map(int, input().split())
x = sorted((xi, i) for i, xi in enumerate(map(int, input().split())))
events = heapq.merge(
    ((xi    , False, i) for xi, i in x),
    ((xi + d, True , i) for xi, i in x)
)

n_tickets = 0
free_tickets = []
assignment = [None] * n
for xi, f, i in events:
    if f:
        free_tickets.append(assignment[i])
    else:
        if free_tickets:
            t = free_tickets.pop()
        else:
            n_tickets += 1
            t = n_tickets
        assignment[i] = t

print(n_tickets)
print(*assignment)
```